# SQL Server 2008 and Windows Firewall issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

I'm trying to connect to a SQL 2008 Express instance on Server 2008 but am having problems with Windows Firewall.  If the firewall is off, I have no issues.

The error provider is SQL Network Interfaces.  I've opened TCP 1433 and UDP 1434 as per many instructions on the ney but to no avail.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to open more ports than just 1433 and 1434. [The full list is documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx). IIS may only need 1433 and 1434 because all it will need is just access to the database engine, but SQL Management studio may need more ports open since it will want to talk to all sorts of other SQL services (e.g. for sql server agent, configuring alerts, logs, settings etc)